# How print files with certain names inside a folder

Tags: python, string, loops

I have a folder with many files that have similar names. This is my code so far.

```
directory = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\AMSRE"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for f in filenames:           
        if f == "AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001?":
            log = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r')
            file_name = (("C:\\Users\\matth\\Downloads\\AMSRE\\") + f)
            print(file_name)
```

However, nothing is printing. I used this line `if f == "AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001?":` because I have many files with similar names:

- `AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_20100101.hdf`,
- `AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_20100102.hdf`,
- `AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_20100103.hdf`,
- and so on.

I'm  not completely sure if I am using the question mark right. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: is this your indentation or did you make a mistake copying?

Comment: Try `if f.startswith("AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001")` instead

Comment: I made a mistake copying

Comment: @inspectorG4dget thank you it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't support wildcards or placeholders like `*` or `?` in normal comparisons. As @inspectorG4dget pointed out in the comments you could just check if it starts with a specific string ([`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)):

```
if f.startswith("AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001"):
```

instead of:

```
if f == "AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001?":
```